# Tidyverse Equivlant to Spark's PolynomialExpansion Function

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, tidyr

Does anything in the `tidyverse` (or `tidyverse`-like `R` packages) have the equivalent of Apache Spark's [PolynomialExpansion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#polynomialexpansion)?

For example, if I have 3 variables (e.g., `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`) I'd like to pass the range of variables and have them interact (e.g., `v1` * `v2`, `v1` * `v3`, ...) with each other automatically.

Comment: http://spark.rstudio.com/ seems like the best bet within/near the 'verse.

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure if OP actually thinks about Spark (sparklyr). If it is the case, then `sparklyr::ft_polynomial_expansion` is the wrapper. But it sound more like plain R question. `model.matrix` would be the first choice, but it is not _tidyverse-like_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R provides `formula` (see Details section of `?formula`) interface to define models in a very concise way. (`tidyverse` itself uses formulae to implement a lot of stuff).

E.g. (as @user8371915 mentioned)

```
model.matrix(~ b + a:c - 1, 
             data_frame(a = 1:10, 
                        b = 1:10,
                        c = 1:10))
```

will give you a model matrix that is easily 'castable' with `dplyr::as_data_frame`:

```
    b a:c
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   4  16
5   5  25
6   6  36
7   7  49
8   8  64
9   9  81
10 10 100
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 2
```

Again, the help for `?formula` tells you:

> The ^ operator indicates crossing to the specified degree. For example (a+b+c)^2 is identical to (a+b+c)*(a+b+c) which in turn expands to a formula containing the main effects for a, b and c together with their second-order interactions

Thus the following will provide a formal way to define polynomial expansion (including intercept)

```
model.matrix(~ (a + b + c)^3, 
             data_frame(a = 1:10, 
                        b = 1:10,
                        c = 1:10))
```

`formula` is one of the most powerful concepts available in R.

**Edit**: add second degree example without intercept

```
aDataFrame <- data_frame(v1 = 1:10, 
                         v2 = 1:10,
                         v3 = 1:10,
                         v4 = 1:10) 

model.matrix(~ (.)^2 - . - 1, aDataFrame)

   v1:v2 v1:v3 v1:v4 v2:v3 v2:v4 v3:v4
1      1     1     1     1     1     1
2      4     4     4     4     4     4
3      9     9     9     9     9     9
4     16    16    16    16    16    16
5     25    25    25    25    25    25
6     36    36    36    36    36    36
7     49    49    49    49    49    49
8     64    64    64    64    64    64
9     81    81    81    81    81    81
10   100   100   100   100   100   100
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks @Drey. I was not familiar with formula so generally speaking that's helpful. Your example though doesn't answer my specific question regarding how to have every variable interact with every other variable (yours us a summation of all variables interacting with itself).

Comment: No, that is not a 'sum', it has a different meaning in the formula . The second example does include interaction up to 3rd degree. Using degree 2 instead should return the disired result? Could you try it and see if it is what you seek?

Comment: I added an example which may be helpful.

Comment: That's perfect @Drey, I've marked it as the answer. Thanks.